# Displaying child json in ag-grid column

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a json object like this

```
[{
    name: 'abcd',
    formData: {
        age: 33
        sex: m
    }
},
{
    name: 'ssabcd',
    formData: {
        age: 23
        sex: m
    }
}]
```

I want to display it like  `{ headerName: 'age', field: 'formData.age' },`

But it is not working and is displaying blank.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to build your own array.

```
gridData=[];

 data=[{
     name: 'abcd',
        formData: {
            age: 33,
            sex: "m"
             }
        },
       {
        name: 'ssabcd',
        formData: {
            age: 23,
            sex:"m" 
        }
       }]
```

**code to build own array**

```
 for(var i=0;i< this.data.length;i++){

    this.gridData.push({name:this.data[i].name,age:this.data[i].formData.age})

    }

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.gridData))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not have **suppressFieldDotNotation** in gripOptions set to true.